# Applescript/Excel Saving Charts as Images

Tags: excel, macos, image, charts, applescript

I am trying to save the first chart in a sheet called charts as a PNG to the desktop.  I get the following error on the "save as picture" line:

error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Parameter error." number -50

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set theChart to first chart object of sheet "Charts"
    set filePath to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Desktop:Chart.png" as text
    save as picture theChart picture type save as PNG file file name filePath
end tell
```

I have also tried telling the chart itself and receiving the same error:

```
tell theChart
    save as picture picture type save as PNG file file name filePath
end tell
```

From the dictionary and other known examples the syntax appears to be correct but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft Office 2016** is very strict for the security when using script.

- If the file already exist, then error number -50.
- if there are no files in this folder in the list of the recent files
  of **Excel**, then error number -50.

---

Solution, use this:

```
set myFolder to path to desktop folder
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    alias myFolder --  first,  need this line to grant access to the folder before saving the PNG file , otherwise --> Parameter error.  number -50
    my deleteIfExists(myFolder, "Chart.png") -- second,  if the file already exists, then delete the file,  otherwise --> Parameter error.  number -50

    set theChart to first chart object of sheet "Charts"
    save as picture theChart picture type save as PNG file file name ((myFolder as string) & "Chart.png")
end tell

on deleteIfExists(f, tName) -- move the file to the trash
    tell application "Finder" to tell item tName of folder f to if exists then delete
end deleteIfExists
```